# How to remove items from contextual action bar android

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I want to remove **COPY, SELECT ALL** and **FIND** from android contextual action bar and add custom menu items.

[image]

This is appearing while selecting text on webview. I am trying to add Text Highlights on webview using js.

Comment: why you not use 3rd party library fro action bar??

Comment: have you check action bar sherlock ??

Comment: i am new to android. please suggest those library.

Comment: CAB is appearing while selecting text on webview. how to disable it.

Comment: your application android:minSdkVersion??

Comment: android:minSdkVersion:8. please tell me how to customize default CAB which appearing on Long press on webview.

Comment: means are you use html controls? not native ?? am I right?

Comment: so sorry.. I have no idea regard that.. I just know native controls!

Comment: shall you please share your mail id. i will send my code..

Answer (score 2):

In order to accomplish what you want, you will need to create an entirely new contextual action bar. This is done through creating a custom `ActionMode`. Within your `WebView`, create a nested class that implements `ActionMode.Callback`. You can use this as a template:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // This block is directly from the WebView source code.
        ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return null;
        }

        mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
        return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown.
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // This method is called when the selection handlebars are moved.
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_button_1:
                // Do stuff
                break;
            case R.id.menu_button_2:
                // Do stuff
                break;
            default:
                // You did not handle the action, so return false
                // If you have implemented a case for every button,
                // this block should never be called.
                return false;
            }

            // If you want to close the CAB immediately after 
            // picking an action, call mode.finish().
            // If you want the CAB to persist until the user clears the selection
            // or clicks the "Done" button, simply return true.
            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mode = null;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Be sure to define a menu in your XML resources. Here is an example to go with the above template:

```
<!-- context_menu.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_button_1"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/menu_button_1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_button_1">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_button_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_button_2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_button_2">
    </item>

</menu>
```

---

I noticed you did not explicitly state that you want to replace **SHARE** and **WEB SEARCH**. Unfortunately, this method does require you to implement all functionality on your own. However, you can dig into the source code (I would start in `ActionMode.java`) for those functions. Implement a new case in `CustomActionModeCallback.onActionItemClicked` (where you handle your button events), copy/paste the functionality from source, and add a corresponding button in your XML file. You can even use the native icon for those functions: `android:icon="@android:drawable/[name_of_desired_icon]`

For reference, this information is from the Android Developers website.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you and also stack members...
`https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection`